# beforeunload not working in Safari 9.1 after the page reloads on clicking leave page button

Tags: jquery, safari, onbeforeunload

In safari 9.1,jquery beforeunload browser pop up doesnt show up for the second time.
Once the user clicks on leave page button in the pop up the page reloads.But after this the pop up never comes up though the controls goes to the code. Unless the browser is reopened again the pop up never shows up.
PFB the code

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if(condition) {
        e.returnValue="";  // for chrome
        return "message";
    }
});
```

Comment: I can confirm this. I have been looking to implement it on Safari for the last couple of hours. Does anyone knows if this is workable? I have my doubts about it since this seems to be the browser's policy to avoid annoying users with abusive prompts.

Comment: I can also confirm this issue. Using the javascript debugger in Safari, the function attached to _onbeforeunload_ event is executed but the leave or stay dialog never appears if the user had previously answered this dialog with a "leave" click.  The only way to restore _correct_ behavior is to close the browser window and reopen. Tested in Safari 9.1.1.

Comment: Is there any solution for this through javascript

Comment: Did anybody found a solution? I'm facing the same issue on mac safari 11.0

Comment: Any updates? I'm struggling with this too. I found a bug report about this: http://www.openradar.me/28814642 that was marked as a duplicate of another issue, but I'm unable to access the original issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it was permanently removed from some browsers due bug.
See chromium description here https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480
and this chrome commit https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/141dbc132f8aa2588fad4cf50fbfd7a319234b61